# how to set a update warning for update too many rows

Tags: mysql

I wanna to stop these query which will update more than 10k row at once.

just like mysql workbench, if i update a table without where condition, it will give me a warning and stop execute the sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no built-in function for this

before you sending the update statement,
you will need to execute the filter condition (ie . `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TBL WHERE...`
in order to get the count of matched rows

from there, you can determine whether it should prompt a warning or not